# Differentiability of smooth functions

Tags: distribution-theory

The space is from Schwartz space $S$ or the space of all smooth functions of compact support $D$.

**Can you say anything about how many times the test function is differentiable from this?**

I think that no, but not completely sure.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Smooth" *means* that the function is differentiable as many times as you want.